# Importing packages from Sitecore through Code

Tags: packages

I want to import the Sitecore packages in Sitecore through code. Is there way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a nice blog post from Akshay Sura describing how to export and import packages:

http://www.webdatasource.com/2011/08/exporting-and-importing-packages-from-sitecore-through-code-using-sitecore-api/

Code for import is:

```
using (new SecurityDisabler())
{
    using (new ProxyDisabler())
    {
        using (new SyncOperationContext())
        {
            IProcessingContext context = new SimpleProcessingContext();
            IItemInstallerEvents events = new DefaultItemInstallerEvents(new BehaviourOptions(InstallMode.Overwrite, MergeMode.Undefined));
            context.AddAspect(events);
            IFileInstallerEvents events1 = new DefaultFileInstallerEvents(true);
            context.AddAspect(events1);

            Sitecore.Install.Installer installer = new Sitecore.Install.Installer();
            installer.InstallPackage(MainUtil.MapPath("INSERT PACKAGE PATH INCLUDING THE FILE NAME"), context);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Your question did not specify which language the code needed to be written in, so here is an example in PowerShell.

```
PS master:\> Install-Package -Path YourPackageName.zip -InstallMode Merge -MergeMode Merge
```

Unless you have a really good reason to use C# code to install the packages, I would recommend you use Sitecore PowerShell Extensions (SPE).

Check out the book for more details:
https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/commands/Install-Package.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use Sitecore API to import the packages. You can use the code like

```
using (new ProxyDisabler())  
    {  
        using (new SyncOperationContext())  
        {  
            IProcessingContext context = new SimpleProcessingContext();  
            IItemInstallerEvents events = new DefaultItemInstallerEvents(new BehaviourOptions(InstallMode.Overwrite, MergeMode.Undefined));  
            context.AddAspect(events);  
            IFileInstallerEvents events1 = new DefaultFileInstallerEvents(true);  
            context.AddAspect(events1);  

            Sitecore.Install.Installer packageInstaller = new Sitecore.Install.Installer();  
            packageInstaller.InstallPackage(MainUtil.MapPath("exact path for package with file name"), context);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Additionally you can use Sitecore API to export the package also.